# iPhone 5 Contacts Underline

Tags: iphone

I've recently had all the info in my Contacts underlined (not the name but phone numbers, addresses, etc.). I hate the look (makes it look busy and it's unnecessary), but have no idea how this occurred. I'm still using the older OS (not 8). Anybody know what I should do to get rid of the underlining?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

To disable Button Shapes, which may be the reason you are seeing lines under certain text, tap Settings > General > Accessibility, and turn off Button Shapes if it is on.